# Como cambiar el error por un mensaje cuando quiero eliminar un FK que el alert me diga que no puede ser borrado por estar en otra tabla

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas como están, espero que estén bien, tengo una pregunta, como puedo cambiar el mensaje de error por un alert, al momento de querer eliminar una FK me sale ese error y quiciera que me aparezca un alert que diga que no se pueda eliminar por que ese dato está siendo utilizado en otro lugar, agradezco sus respuestas! Gracias!!
Solucionado! Lo hice de la siguiente manera

```css
//borrar datos
    } elseif ($_GET['act'] == 'delete') {
        if (isset($_GET['emp_cod'])) {
            $codigo = $_GET['emp_cod'];
            $fkmp="SELECT emp_cod FROM pedido_mp where emp_cod='$codigo'";
            $resulmp = $mysqli->query($fkmp);
            $cantmp = mysqli_num_rows($resulmp);

            $fkcc="SELECT emp_cod FROM cont_calid where emp_cod='$codigo'";
            $resulcc = $mysqli->query($fkcc);
            $cantcc = mysqli_num_rows($resulcc);
```

Comment: Se necesita un muestra de tu html y tu javascript para ayudarte

Comment: Como diceNarciso, tienes que adjuntar el código para poder dar una solución, pero en este caso solo te puedo decir que tienes que hacer uso de try/catch

Comment: Aparte de añadir tú código te aconsejo que le des un ojo a este enlace https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php . No puedes llevar a cabo la eliminación de tu query por cómo tienes configurada tu FK. Si añades tu código te hecho una mano, de otra forma es complicado ayudarte...

Comment: Logré solucionarlo amigos! lo hice de la siguiente manera !

Comment: @xmaname por favor publica la solución en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta